# iphone - how to add normal text to settings bundle

Tags: iphone, settings, label

I've 3 groups created in iphone settings bundle Root.plist file.
Its showing fine.

But for every group, i want to add some description. It will be something like follows:

GroupName
Description
Settings in that group.

Is it possible. How to add description? If the description color is different to identify from group name and settings in that group, it will be good.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can add text at the bottom of your Groups, that is commonly used as a hint about the preferences in that group.

1. Add a new item to a Group (Yes!, additionally to the default `Title` and `Type` Keys).
2. Replace the text under the Key column that reads "New Item" for `FooterText`.
3. Under the Type column set the type for you new Key as `String`.
4. Write whatever you want on the field under the Value column for the new Key.

And... voilà!

Next time you build and launch the App go to Settings and to your App's preferences to see the text under the Group you placed it.

Answer (score 6):

Theres a type called PSChildPaneSpecifier which shows a new page of string content. So update your Root.plist like this:

```
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSChildPaneSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>LicenseAgreementTitle</string>
        <key>File</key>
        <string>License</string>
    </dict>
```

And create a License.strings file in your locale folder inside the Settings.bundle:

```
"Part1": "First paragraph"
"Part2": "Second paragraph"
```

And you need a License.plist next to Root.plist too to list your parts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>StringsTable</key>
        <string>License</string>
        <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>Type</key>
                <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
                <key>FooterText</key>
                <string>Part1</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>Type</key>
                <string>PSGroupSpecifier</string>
                <key>FooterText</key>
                <string>Part2</string>
            </dict>
        </array>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I found this in the Apple Remote application by extracting the ipa file.

Comment: Useful answer, I had to reformat the .strings file to look like `"Part1" = "First paragraph"; "Part2" = "Second paragraph";` also adding a title key is useful see here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSGroupSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007009-SW1

Answer (score 5):

everything you will ever need for setings.bundle is here ->

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Introduction/Introduction.html

however, choosing colors etc isn't going to happen. sorry.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the font to be **bold** just paste a formatted text into the `Title` property of the group.

Comment: What do you mean by formatted text? formatted how? Please [edit] to explain further