# How to show a clickable link in iOS app setting?

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

I was able to add a new section "Legal" in my app settings using Settings.bundle, and the content was displayed as group titles. There are links in the legal statement but cannot be clicked. How to make these links clickable?

Comment: How do you show the `Settings.bundle`? Can you show us your codes?

Comment: The method I used [best way to add license section to iOS settings bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428353/best-way-to-add-license-section-to-ios-settings-bundle/6453507#6453507)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's any way to use hyperlinks in Settings.bundle.

[Earlier stackoverflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959274/how-can-you-launch-a-url-from-the-ios-settings-bundle)

A legal statement isn't a setting - why not just have a separate view in your app with the statement?

Comment: There are links in Settings > General > About > Legal.

Comment: It's possible to [display text using FooterText below a group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192526/iphone-how-to-add-normal-text-to-settings-bundle) but AFAIK there's no way to embed a hyperlinks within that text. AFAICR I've only seen hyperlinks in iOS built-in apps e.g. Facebook, Twitter.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to keep it simple and will not use a separate view. I'll use the legal statement without hyperlinks.